# Misunderstanding labels in TFS / VS 2010

Tags: tfs, label

I have several files I'd like to label.  When I click on one I can select "Apply Label..." and I can create and apply the label.  But if I right-click another file I don't see any mechanism for applying a pre-existing label?  All I'm presented with is the same dialog used to create another label, or edit the existing one.

I've looked on MSDN and have had no luck with figuring out how to create a label and then apply it to various files.  Or am I missing the purpose of labels in some way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct - this is because in Team Foundation Server, labels **contain** files, files don't **have** labels.

To include another file in a label, you can locate the Label in History, select Edit Label and then add the other item(s).