# Apply label to multiple files in the same folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using VS.NET 2012 and TFS 2013. I needed to apply label to multiple **text** files in the same folder. But "Apply Label" is disabled when multiple text files are selected.

It looks like label can be applied to the folder or to a single file but not multiple files in the same folder.

One option I see is to edit the label and add files later. Is there other way to apply label to multiple text files in the same folder?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691988/misunderstanding-labels-in-tfs-vs-2010

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio, labels can only be created against a single item in version control; i.e. a branch or folder (which includes all files under it automatically) or an individual file.

Using the command line you can select the files you want by supplying one or more item specs, something like this will work:

`tf label MyLabel *.txt`

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew32kd1.aspx